# Simplemodal pop-out window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

So, If you go to www.leapfm.com and click sign-up or log in it re-directs you to a new page. However, I'd like the window to pop-out instead for a better user experience.

I've tried using [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) for this but can't seem to get it working.

I've put the simplemodal.js file in my assets/javascript.

And then subsequently made a new file called popout.js with the class I'd like to popout (the sign up, log in form)

```
$(".form-1").modal();
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. What can I do to get this to work?/ to get the login and sign-up windows to be popouts instead.

**more code:**

```
.form-1 {
    position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative; /* For the submit button positioning */

    /* Styles */
    box-shadow:
        0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
        0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
        inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,1),
        inset 0 -3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(#eeefef, #ffffff 10%);
}
```

**log-in:**

```
<div class="form-1">
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= content_tag(:div, flash[:error], :id => "flash_error") if flash[:error] %>
<%= content_tag(:div, flash[:alert], :id => "flash_alert") if flash[:alert] %>

<br />

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't look it, do you use team-viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use [jQueryui Modal Form](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)

Copy the jquery-ui in your app/assets/javascripts.

Its very easy to integrate in your rails application.

Make your link_to that opens the form partial as remote true. It pops up at the snap of your finger.

Example,

```
<%= link_to "Register",new_user_path,{:remote => :true} %>
```

in your, **app/views/new.js.erb**

```
$("#new-form").dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
  width: 650,
  height: 800,
  modal: true,
  draggable:true,
  resizable:false,
  buttons: [
       {
            text: "CLOSE",
            className: 'close-button-class',
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    ],
  open: function() {
    $("#new-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('form')) %>");
    }
});
```

**app/views/user/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```